# RegEx Find and Replace Sentence

Tags: regex, replace, find, sentence

I'm looking for a way to find and replace a sentence using regex. The regex should be able to find a sentence of any length. I can get the entire sentence with .* but that doesn't allow it to replace with \1.

```
FIND:
"QUESTION1" = "What is the day satellite called?"
"ANSWER1" = "The sun"

REPLACE:
<key>What is the day satellite called?</key>
<key>The sun</key>
```

Comment: which language you are using for this

Comment: Sorry, I'm using grep in BBEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use capturing groups. So that you can refer the captured groups through back-reference.

Regex:

```
.*(?<= \")([^"]*).*
```

Replacement string:

```
<key>\1</key>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hN3iE2/2)

Comment: Thanks Avinash! Works great. I'd been struggling with this for a while and it was some tricky than first anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

Find using the following expression (modifiers required: `g` and `m`):

```
^[^=]+= "(.*?)"$
```

and then replace them using:

```
<key>$1</key>
```

or

```
<key>\1</key>
```

Answer (score 0):

using perl:

```
> cat temp
"QUESTION1" = "What is the day satellite called?"
"ANSWER1" = "The sun"

> perl -lne 'print "<key>".$1."<\/key>" if(/\".*?\".*?\"(.*?)\"/)' temp
<key>What is the day satellite called?</key>
<key>The sun</key>
>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl One-Liner

**A compact approach:** search for `(?m)"([^"]+)"$`

Replace with `<key>$1</key>` if you want `<key>What is the day satellite called?</key>`

or

Replace: `"<key>$1</key>"` if you want `"<key>What is the day satellite called?</key>"`

With a perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's!(?m)"([^"]+)"$!<key>$1</key>!g' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are coming from google search, you can play with this great tool here to find the right `regex` expression to use:  http://regexr.com/